# Android App with Cordova – save data using localstorage delayed?

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

This is my first app. It will allow you to make an entry, add that entry to a list and then keep going.

The issue I am having is that if I close the app right after I set a value to the localstorage, it will not save unless I give it 5-10 seconds.

Example:
If I enter in 1 name, click done and then close all apps. The app will load without any data. If I then do the same thing but wait 5-10 seconds before closing the app, when I open the app it will have the correct data.

The same can be said for the clear.

When testing this in a normal browser, everything works just fine.

**Side note: yes I know it is saving a bunch of HTML with each name. I want it that way. Unless that is why I am having this issue, but I would not think it would be a problem on my 2 week old Tab S

Here is my code

Thoughts?

HTML/CSS

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <title>first app</title>
  <style>
   .clear {clear:both;}
   
   #all_content {margin:20px 0 0 100px}
   #new_char {margin-top:20px;}
   #new_character_name_input_container{float:left;}
   #new_character_name_button_container {float:left;}
   #exsisting_char {display:none;}
   
   #character_list {margin:20px 0 0 0;}
   .character_name {float:left;}
  </style>
    </head>
    <body>
  <div id="all_content">
   <div style="border-bottom:1px solid #000000; width:200px;">Items retrieved on load</div>
   <div id="data_dump">
   </div>
   <input id="new_char" type="button" value="Create New Character">
   
   <div id="character_list">
    
   </div>
   
   <div id="character_data">
    
   </div>
   <br><br><br><br>
   <input id="clear_all" type="button" value="Clear All">
  </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

here is the JS

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 // get the characters
 $('#data_dump').append('<div id="stored_character_list">'+window.localStorage.getItem('list_of_characters')+'</div>')
  
 // get the characters
 $('#character_list').append(window.localStorage.getItem('list_of_characters'))
 
 // make a new character
 $('#new_char').click(function() {
  
  // keep inserting more than one new character entry
  if ($('#all_content').html().indexOf('new_character_name_container') != -1){
   // do nothing
  }
  else{
   
   //insert input to enter new character
   var new_charater_input_content = '<div id="new_character_name_container"><div id="new_character_name_input_container"><input id="new_character_name_input" type="text" value=""></div><div id="new_character_name_button_container"><input id="new_character_name_button" type="button" value="Done"></div><div id="exsisting_char">Cant Make Doubles</div><div class="clear"></div></div>'
   $('#new_char').after(new_charater_input_content)
   
   // animate the new character input onto the screen
   $('#new_character_name_container').slideDown('fast')
   
   // set focus on new input
   $('#new_character_name_input').focus()
   
   // add the new character to the localstorage new character value
   $('#new_character_name_button').click(function() {
    var new_charater = $('#new_character_name_input').val()
    
    // append the new character to the bottom of the character listing
    $('#character_list').append('<div class="character_list_item"><div class="character_name">'+new_charater+'</div></div>')
    
    // save all the characters to storage
    window.localStorage.setItem('list_of_characters', $('#character_list').html())
    //alert(window.localStorage.getItem('list_of_characters'))
    
   });
  }
  
 });
 
 
 $('#clear_all').click(function() {
  window.localStorage.clear();
 });
 
});
```

Comment: Hmm.  Only thing that really jumps out to me at a quick glance is you are using jQuery's ready event instead of the Cordova deviceready.  Any difference if you wait for device ready? `document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is my problem

[localstorage timeout issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=479767)

There is a issue with localstorage in the version of Android i have.